# How to add an include directory in my solution in Visual Studio C++ so to keep it consistent with Git

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have a project which is version-controlled via git. I work on it from two different locations. Therefore I need to add libraries and headers to the project in a convenient way so that the two version remain consistent across loading external libraries and includes.

I have `SQLiteCpp` Folder, inside which there are several `.h` files. I can add `SQLiteCpp` directory to my visual studio solution via adding it to include directory. but, I don't know how should I do that so it be considered as a source code, and on `'committing'` it, I also commit these libraries, and when I load them from the second location, I `'pull'` the libraries too. Now, if I add a hard-path such as `c://libraries/SQLiteCpp/` to my `#inlude` directories of my project, I then must make a similar path in my secondary machine which seems unreliable. How should I then link it seamlessly in my project? Because SQLite cpp files include these headers like this:

```
#include <SQLiteCpp/column.h>
```

Comment: Include paths can be relative to the project.  Unless you have a very strange directory structure you should be able to make that work.

Comment: Well, I got it man. Thanks. I already have done than relative path-ing. Thanks